# Atmega32u4 external 8MHz clock

Tags: arduino-leonardo, atmega32u4

Does anyone know how to configure the Atmega32u4 to run using an external 8MHz oscillator ?

I needs to still be responsive to the Arduino IDE

Thanks

Comment: The ATmega32U4 is configured by default to work with an external 8MHz crystal.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, per Table 28-5 in Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf, the -RC models of 32U4 are configured for RC operation :)  See note 1,  “1. The default setting of CKSEL3..0 results in Low Power Crystal Oscillator for ATmega16U4 and ATmega32U4, and Internal RC oscillator for ATmega16U4RC and ATmega32U4RC.”

Answer (score 1):

See §28.2 in [Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf), which explains usage of various fuse bits.

Also see [engbedded.com/fusecalc](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/), which lets you easily figure out fuse settings.  Fusecalc also tells you the strings to use as part of avrdude command strings.

Once you know the fuse settings, send them to your device via a command like

```
avrdude -p m32u4 -c usbasp -u -U lfuse:w:0xEF:m -U hfuse:w:0xD5:m -U efuse:w:0x07:m
```

or like

```
avrdude -p m32u4 -P $port -c arduino -u -U lfuse:w:0xEF:m -U hfuse:w:0xD5:m -U efuse:w:0x07:m
```

where `$port` represents a port name like `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Note, it makes sense to read the fuses first, and put the readings into Fusecalc to see what they correspond to.  You can read the fuses via a command like

```
avrdude -p m32u4 -P $port -c arduino -U hfuse:r:-:i
```

Comment: Hi Thanks I see your point and i thought I had to change the fuse settings too, for external 8MHz clock operation with the at328p..... but you don't. The fuse settings are the same.

Comment: Why do I know this... well I read the data sheet and the settings for the atmega328 are the same for both Uno (atmega328p, 5v, 16MHz) and pro(atmega328, 3.3v  8MHz). see the boards.txt file inside arduino application. The only difference is the High fuse which is nothing todo with clock speed

Comment: Sorry I was answering something else :/ hahaha I think you have both given me the answer I needed........ I just need to change to CKDIV8

Comment: I've been head banging all day on this. I only have at328p's to test on still waiting on my 32u4's to be delivered.

Comment: @DannyJ, re your second comment,  “settings for the atmega328 are the same for both Uno (atmega328p, 5v, 16MHz) and pro(atmega328, 3.3v 8MHz)”, right.  The same sort of thing will apply on the 32U4, with the same settings at 8 to 16 MHz Low Power Crystal, and other settings for lower frequencies, as shown in  Table 6-3 of  Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf.   Note, if by “responsive to the Arduino IDE” you mean that `millis()` reports correctly, that is controlled by correctly setting the  `.build.f_cpu` parameter in the appropriate boards.txt section.